# Why Google direction and distance matrix API show different results for source and destination value

Tags: android, google-directory-api, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to get distance and duration using google direction API

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origins=latitude,longitude&destinations=latitude,longitude&&mode=driving&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

and its working fine and get the distance and duration like this

```
  distance="30 m"
  duration="1 min"
```

when am trying get distance and duration using distancematrix api,

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=latitude,longitude&destinations=latitude,longitude&&mode=driving&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

```
  "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1.2 km",
                  "value" : 1168
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 mins",
                  "value" : 140
               }
```

**Note: Passing same latitude and longitude values for both API.
Why both API showing different results for same latitude and longitude values?**

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: @gaurang check my post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286190/4685284